# Flutter list view in not scrolling to the bottom, it drags instead then go upwards

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this issue where list view scrolling is not behaving properly, i know that nested ListViews can cause this type of issues but I have tried different approached with same result.

So the widget consists of a Column with a header and inside the Column there is a ListView with a Tabbar. Scrolling now is hanging as if i am draging the screen, and whenever I release my finger it goes back upward.

```
 Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(children: [
  Container(
    color: AppColor.mainGreenColor,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 24),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.maybePop(context);
            },
            child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/back_arrow_white.svg"),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          const Expanded(
            child: Text(
              "Alerts & Subscriptions",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontFamily: 'Museo Sans',
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 24)
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Expanded(
      child: ListView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
        Builder(
            builder: (context) => DefaultTabController(
                length: 2, // length of tabs
                initialIndex: 0,
                child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return DefaultTabController(
                      initialIndex: 0,
                      length: 2,
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: TabBar(
                                labelColor: AppColor.primaryColor,
                                unselectedLabelColor:
                                    CustomerColors().boughtSold,
                                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                labelStyle: AppFont.customerSoldBought(),
                                indicator: const BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(
                                      bottom: BorderSide(
                                          color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                                          width: 4)),
                                ),
                                onTap: (index) async {
                                  setState(() {
                                    tabIndex = index;
                                  });
                                },
                                tabs: [
                                  const Tab(text: 'ALERTS'),
                                  const Tab(text: 'SUBSCRIPTIONS'),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Column(children: [
                              Container(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                //height of TabBarView
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                        top: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            width: 0.5))),
                                child: TabBarView(
                                    physics:
                                        const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      ListView(
                                        children: [],
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 10,
                                          ),
                                          tabIndex == 1
                                              ? HeaderFilter(
                                                  filterSelected:
                                                      filterSelected,
                                                  filterItems: filterItems,
                                                )
                                              : SizedBox(),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: ListView(
                                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                                children: subscriptionsModel
                                                    .map((e) {
                                                  return SuscriptionItem(
                                                    popupActionSelected:
                                                        popupActionSelected,
                                                    index:
                                                        subscriptionsModel
                                                            .indexOf(e),
                                                    subscriptionModel: e,
                                                  );
                                                }).toList()),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ]),
                              )
                            ])
                          ]));
                })))
      ])),
  Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0, left: 30.0),
      child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: AppButtonStyle.SelectedButtonLargeReport(),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => CreateSubscription()));
            },
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text('New Alert Subscription'),
              ],
            ),
          ))),
])));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Listview.builder below

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder( // Changed to ListView.builder
      itemCount: subscriptionsModel.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return SuscriptionItem(
          popupActionSelected: popupActionSelected,
          index: index,
          subscriptionModel: subscriptionsModel[index],
        );
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, you don't need to create a custom app bar from the container widget; Flutter already provides you with the appBar attribute and the AppBar widget. Just call the appBar key within the Scaffold widget.
2. As far as I can understand from your code, you're trying to place a button at the bottom center. It would be easier to do this using the floatingActionButton and floatingActionButtonLocation attributes provided by the Scaffold.
3. I've written what I understand from your code in a clear manner. I hope this helps your needs :)

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: Scaffold(
              floatingActionButtonLocation:
                  FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
              floatingActionButton: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                child: const Text("New Alert Subscription"),
              ),
              appBar: AppBar(
                bottom: const TabBar(tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    text: "Alerts",
                  ),
                  Tab(text: "Subscriptions"),
                ]),
                title: const Text("Flutter"),
              ),
              body: const TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Tom(),
                  Cruise(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

```
    class Tom extends StatelessWidget {
      const Tom({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: const Center(
            child: Text("mission is not impossible :)"),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

```
    class Cruise extends StatelessWidget {
      const Cruise({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: 80,
                    itemBuilder: (c, i) => Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          width: 100,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          ),
                          child: Center(child: Text("filter item $i")),
                        )),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: List.generate(100, (i) => Text("$i")).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```